# Steam will not work on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, steam

so I had to get Ubuntu and I have no idea what I am even doing. and I NEED STEAM! so I download it and nothing it won't open so can you very smart people help me????????

Comment: Open a terminal ctrl+alt+t and enter steam so you get an output of what is wrong then edit your question to include whats the error messages. Please dont post a screenshot, simply copy and paste it.

Answer (score 2):

To install steam open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install steam
```

Then the launcher should be available in the HUD

Reference this if you get lost somewhere:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/install-steam-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts